# Get parent node from XPATH descendant value

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium

I have a HTML structure that I am attempting to test using XPATH. The structure I'll looking at currently is something like:

```
<div id="item_1" class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="container item">

        <div class="container-header">
            <h2 id="title">test-title</h2>
            <h5 id="description">test-description</h5>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

There are a number of 'items' in my document, each with a unique ID. Using XPATH I want to 'get' the item_1 node from the value of the `title` id node ("test-title" in this case).

I also want to do this in such a way that is not dependant on the node tag (`div`/`h2`/etc).

I've been playing around with predicates, but I can't seem to get a solution that works. For example:

```
//*[@class="item-wrapper"][./*[@id="title"][text()="test-title"]]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the below XPATH :

```
 //*[@id="title"]/ancestor::*[@id="item_1"][1]
```

Or, you can also use the function [***`Function: node-set id(object)`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-id)

```
 id('title')//ancestor::*[@id="item_1"][1]
```

**Update**

```
 //*[.="test-title"]/ancestor::*[@class="item-wrapper"][1]
```

**output**

```
<div id="item_1" class="item-wrapper">
    <div class="container item">

        <div class="container-header">
            <h2 id="title">test-title</h2>
            <h5 id="description">test-description</h5>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I'm looking to do this without referencing the id directly, as they are auto-generated and unique. I also wanted it to search by the text value of `title`, as mentioned above. Your answer pointed me in the right direction though, the `/ancestor::*` was the bit I was missing.

FYI, the answer to my issue was: `//*[@id="title"][text()="test-title"]/ancestor::*[@class="item-wrapper"]`